# Observer with multiple subjects using std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, observer-pattern

I have seen implementations of the Observer design pattern in which the Observer is responsible for multiple Subjects. Most of these implementations use a `std::vector<Subject*>` in order to keep track of the Subjects.

Would it be possible for me to do a similar thing, using a `std::unordered_set<weak_ptr<Subject>>` instead?

The reason I want to use an `unordered_set` is that I will not need duplicates, and I don't need an ordered container. From what I understand, an `unordered_set` is the way to go in this situation. Also, the reason I am using a `weak_ptr` is that it should be safer?

If you disagree, leave an answer explaining what container I should use instead. If I did use the `unordered_set`, I would have to declare a hash function for the `weak_ptr`, but could this be accomplished by just using the hash function for the pointer inside, obtained with `subjects.lock().get()`?

Comment: Normally, with the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) the Subject has a collection of registered Observers and the Observers don't actually need to know what they are observing.  They just get notified by the Subject when something changes. What is this set of Subjects for? Is it so that the Observer can deregister itself when it is deleted?

Comment: In the implementation I was looking at, the Observer used either a Subject* or a vector<Subject*> in order to keep track. Without these, how do they update when they are notified of a change? Won't they need to look "through" the pointer in order to see what has changed? It would also be useful for automatically deregistering itself in the destructor.

Comment: The subject notifies the observer by invoking a function on it which also gets a pointer or reference to the subject as parameter. From that parameter the observer can tell which subject has changed.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TheoSandstrom There are basically two ways of running things. The "push" model where the notify call includes all the information the Observer needs. Or the "pull" model where the notify call just says something has changed and it is up to the Observer to go and figure out what. In the "pull" model the Observer will probably want to know what the _types_ of Subjects it is observing. Either way, as Alexander says, it is worth sending a pointer or reference to the subject as a parameter.

Comment: @ChrisDrew What do I do if I need the Observer to call a `command` function on every Subject that it is attached to. Wouldn't I need to keep a list of attached Subjects?

Comment: @TheoSandstrom, Sure, that's fine. I'm not saying what you are doing is wrong. I was just trying to find out what this set was for.

Comment: @ChrisDrew OK! I will go ahead like this. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in my answer I will use Subject as the one who sends messages to registered Observers, since it is the common use of this two terms.

> Would it be possible for me to do a similar thing, using a `std::unordered_set<weak_ptr<Observer>>` instead?

It is possible. However remeber that the object held by a weak_ptr can be freed, weak_ptr needs to be casted to a shared_ptr before accessing the underlying object. It is done this way so the object is not freed while you are handling it.

> Would it be possible for me to do a similar thing, using a std::unordered_set> instead?

If you need to enforce uniqueness the unordered_set looks like a good choice to me. If you don't need to, then a vector is more straightforward solution. Some would tell that unique_set is slower and requires more memory than a vector, but unless you need very high frequency registration of Observers or thousands of them, you won't notice the difference.

About the weak pointer, it gives you the flexibility of having your Observers deallocated while registered, so it should be fine. This behaviour may be unexpected if you come from a memory managed language like Java. If you want to hold them in existence while they are registered in your Subject you may use a shared_pointer instead.

> I would have to declare a hash function for the weak_ptr, but could this be accomplished by just using the hash function for the pointer inside, obtained with observer.lock().get()?

Be careful when creating hash functions, I dont recommend you to use object's pointer for the hash function, specially if your Subjects can be copied/moved. Instead you may create an unique identifier for every Subject upon creation using a counter, and remember to write copy/move constructors and operators accordingly.

If you cannot write an identifying hash function, then you should't use the unique_set, since you lose the advantages it brings.

As a footnote, the beauty of object containers is that you can fit them to your needs, every solution is the correct solution if it does what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

In the Observer pattern the Observer subscribes to notifications about changes on a Subject. The Subject is responsible for updating all subscribed Observers whenever its observable state changes. For that to work the Observers do not need to keep track of the Subjects. Instead the Subject must keep track of all subscribed Observers.

A nice explanation of the Observer pattern can be found here: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer

Code outline:

```
class Subject;

class Observer
{
public:
    // when notified about a change, the Observer
    // knows which Subject changed, because of the parameter s
    virtual void subjectChanged(Subject* s)=0;

};

class Subject
{
private:
    int m_internalState;
    std::set<Observer*> m_observers;

public:
    void subscribe(Observer* o)
    {
        m_observers.insert(o);
    }

    void unsubscribe(Observer* o);
    {
        m_observers.erase(o);
    }

    void setInternalState(int state)
    {
        auto end=m_observers.end();
        for(auto it=m_observers.begin(); it != end; ++it)
            it->subjectChanged(this);
    }

};
```

In most cases it won't matter which exact collection type you choose for storing the Observers, because there will be very few Observers. However, choosing a set-type has the advantage, that each Observer will receive only one notification. With a `vector` it could happen that the same Observer receives multiple notifications about the same change, if (for some reason) it was subscribed multiple times.

Comment: Was not me.  But you can always check if the item already exists in the vector before inserting it for the same effect but will use less memory and it will be faster notifying subjects - which is the code that is called the most.

Comment: I downvoted you because your approach involves way too much duplication for every signature and every different kind of subject and observer, instead of a single generic solution that applies for every signature, subject, and observer.

Comment: @Puppy If you have Observer and Subject base classes then why does there need to be any code duplication?

Comment: Well, that would require them to be effectively universal base classes, which is such a tremendously bad idea that I could not fit in this comment all the reasons why it's awful. Furthermore, there's absolutely no need for it whatsoever when you could just write one class template that covers all cases without pointless base classes and has actual type safety.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich In practice, I would expect `subjectChanged` to be `virtual` and probably abstract.

Comment: @Puppy: not very sportmanslike, to downvote if you plan to post an answer yourself...

Comment: @Alex: It's perfectly sportsmanlike. The existing answers were insufficient and wrong, so I had to step in.

Comment: @Puppy:  Alex's solution wasn't wrong so it doesn't merit a down vote.  If you feel you can improve the solution, then either post a new solution or provide constructive feedback in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really one 'correct' answer for the choice of container; it depends upon what you are aiming for from the point of view of performance.  And whether or not performance is really all that important for this.

It also depends upon memory efficiency.  If you only have a few of these unordered_set objects and need very fast lookup then it may be a good choice.  Since it is a hash table it will use a fairly large amount of memory per unordered_set object.

If you have a lot of unordered_set objects with fairly few items then it may get a bit expensive in terms of memory budget.  If you need fast insertion and removal then std::set may be better in this case.  However if the collection only ever contains a handful of items then the lookup will probably actually be faster with a linear search of std::vector due to the processor cache (i.e. better locality of reference of the vector elements compared to std::set - which may result in more elements being on the same cache line).  Memory usage of vector will be lower than either of std::set or std::unordered_set.

If you need fast lookup of specific objects for some reason and use std::vector and typically have a a moderate number of elements then you could insert items into the vector in sorted order.  You can then use std::lower_bound to do an O(log n) binary search lookup.  However, this has a potentially high cost for inserting and removing elements.

I'd probably just go for std:vector in most cases - you generally have few observers, so may as well keep memory usage tighter.
And using weak_ptr is certainly a good option if these objects are used elsewhere with shared_ptr.

Comment: I downvoted you because your answer involves re-implementing boost but substantially worse and with a lot more effort.

Comment: what do you mean?  boost signals has extremely poor performance.  I wrote my own signals library that does the same thing but is over 10x faster than boost when profiling with aqtime.  Mind you have not tried signals2

Comment: @Puppy The question was on the merits of using unordered_set anyway which is why I answered this way.  He did not ask how to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Signals2 is years old... if you only have experience with regular signals that's far too old to be material now. Furthermore, even if you argue that the *implementation* of Signals2 is too slow, that does not merit changing the *interface*.

Comment: There's a difference between not asking how to avoid code duplication, and requiring massive code duplication to get anywhere, in the sake of performance that isn't even benefitted by the duplication...

Comment: I wrote my own library about 10 years ago anyway.  Its been profiled, its bug free & works well.  Do't really need the boost version personally but I expect the interface is good going by the rest of boost.  If coming to it new today I would probably use the boost offering.  At the time, it was identified as a bottleneck in an application I was writing so I changed it.

Comment: @Puppy going by your reputation, I'm guessing you realize this s a question and answer site.  I answered the question.  I think your down-vote is unfair for that reason but I guess that's your choice anyway.  Thanks for explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

I really think that using `std::unordered_set` is a bit over-kill.
what is this observer pattern? when an event or a change of state occurs, iterate over an array of state-checkers and make them do something if the state is invalid or special in any sort.

this has being said, you want to iterate over an array with objects with overriden virtual function and call it. why whould `set` give us any benefit?
also, I don't get the `weak_ptr` idea - the owner of the observers is the array with holds them. the owner of that array is the Subject.

now that all has being said, I would go with `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Observer>>`.

Edit:

using C++11, I'd even go with `std::vector<std::function<void(Subject&)>>` and avoid the boilerplate of inheriting+overriding.

Comment: `unique_ptr` is not a good idea, it'll delete the Observer once it's unsubscribed from the Subject or the Subjects life time ends. That's virtually always inappropriate.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem. if you detach an observer, probably you don't need it anymore. when you want to attach one , just use `make_unique`

Answer (score -2):

The simplest thing to do is to roll with `boost::signals2`, which already implemented this for you, for all signatures. The fundamental problem with your approach is that the implementation is tied to a particular signature with a particular subject and observer, which is virtually worthless compared to a generic solution that applies for all cases.

The Observer pattern is not a pattern, it's a class template.